# In citizen sleeper, why are the people whose minds been copied to create Sleepers, kept in cryosleep?

Tags: androids, cryogenics

In the video game Citizen Sleeper, the titular Sleepers are biomechanical constructs controlled by an emulated human mind. In the setting, there is a general ban on sentient AI, and sleepers are a sort-of loophole around this rule. They are employed in hard and difficult work where humans are not strong or resilient enough, but simple non-sentient robots don't have enough problem-solving capabilities.
They are created by scanning the brain of a human, stripping it of memories of that individual's former life (even though the procedure is not 100% thorough), ending up in a mostly blank state, which can now take control over a robotic body, while having the mental capabilities of a human. These sleepers are legally not treated as persons (despite themselves feeling themselves as being persons), are considered completely disposable, and as the properties of the corporations which created them. People whose brains are scanned are payed for this, so usually desperate or indebted people undergo this procedure.

However, it is implied several times in the story, that the human whose brain was scanned to create the sleeper, is kept in cryosleep during the entire lifetime of the sleeper. And this is what I don't understand at all. Why would the corporation do so? The sleepers, once created, have their minds of their own, they are not the same person. They are forced to do hard and dangerous labor and are prevented from escaping both by force and by an artificially short lifespan, making their bodies quickly deteriorate without a regular supply of special company-produced chemicals. But what advantage could that company have by keeping the original human in cryosleep? That certainly requires resources, it's an expenditure, so why not just let them go after their brains were scanned? What would the company gain from keeping them there while the sleepers work? After the sleepers have been built, they have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed by the game's creator in an interview. In brief, your real self has built up debts. By cloning your consciousness you can enter cryosleep and emerge debt free, with no memory of what your digital clone has been up to.

> "Imagine you could sign yourself up to be copied," Damian Martin says.
> **"This copy of you could then be put in a digital body and work for
> you, clearing your debts and earning you money while you slept. You
> would never have to experience the work, or the suffering of your
> copy, and one day you could just wake up with your debt cleared, money
> in your pocket and walk out.** In Citizen Sleeper you are one of these
> copies, a sleeper, a dead end of a life, meant to be deleted, but who
> escaped from the system.
>
> "This kind of debt-slavery is something we can see versions of in our
> society, in structures such as Uber which promise freedom but control
> both their workers' debt (when buying a car to use as a taxi) and the
> methods of repayment."
>
> <sub><sup>[Like most great sci-fi, Citizen Sleeper has something to say about the here and now](https://www.pcgamer.com/like-most-great-sci-fi-citizen-sleeper-has-something-to-say-about-the-here-and-now/)</sup></sub>

What isn't clear is whether the sleeping is mandatory or necessary, but it would appear that this is part of a package deal. You sleep and awake debt free.

Comment: Yes, Uber is very similar. I mean, you might be able to leave whenever you find an alternate means of financial support (or in some countries, be supported by the social safety net), and choose your hours, and keep your memories, but Uber drivers sometimes sleep in their cars, and that's *basically* the same.